# Is there a way to store the ListView item number in an int in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, int, listviewitem

I imported a text file into a `ListView` in android.

If I click an item in `listView`,  it's `line number` should be stored in an `int`.

For example (this is a `ListView` (text file)):

```
Corn (1)
Apple (2)
Melon (3)
```

If a line is clicked for example `Melon`, it's line number (3) should be stored in an `int`.

```
The code:
```

// returns index to -1

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {



                        boolean co = true;

                        int lineNumber = list.getSelectedItemPosition();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(lineNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used int `position` included in the method:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                             int position, long id)

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Item No:"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Note Item index start with 0.

Method like this may also help you

```
listView.getSelectedItemPosition()
listView.getCheckedItemPosition()
```

Note: This above two line is not meant for item click.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain what's the difference ? I'm very sorry I'm a newbie.

Comment: try like this
`int lineNumber = listView.getSelectedItemPosition()`

Comment: Wait, I converted int to string and put it into a toast. The toast always said -1. Instead of (4th item in listview is clicked -> 4 should appear in the toast)

Comment: If you are trying like this then no need to call list.getSelectedItemPosition().
parameter position in your onItemClick is the required item number. Check edited answer. Hope it helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ListView index starts from zero, so the index should be like this

```
Corn (0)
Apple (1)
Melon (2)
```

And easily you can get the position of the selected item as it's declared as a parameter in

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

And also you can get the name of the selected item by this line in onItemClick()

```
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                String title = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }
```